# How to provide Mono Consumers as method arguments?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a generic method that executes a bunch of requests in parallel, sends them to an external web api, and collects the results.

Problem: the caller should be able to provide success and error handlers for the subroutine of the web request. But how?

Example:

```
public <Req, Rsp> List<Rsp> sendApiRequests(List<Req> requests, Class<Rsp> type) {
    return Flux.fromIterable(requests)
            .flatMap(req -> webClient.post()
                       .uri(uri)
                       .bodyValue(req)
                       .retrieve()
                       .bodyToMono(type)
                       .//TODO how can I add a generic handler methods here?
                       .)
            .filter(rsp -> rsp.success() && rsp.results > 0) //some common filters
            .collectList()
            .block();
}
```

The caller should be able to provide a *subroutine* that could very. Eg it could provide a `.doOnSuccess()`, a `.doOnerror()` or a `.onErrorMap()` function. Also any other or all of them.

Pseudocode:

```
sendApiRequests(req, MyDto.class, req -> <subroutine>.doOnSuccess(..)
                                                     .doOnError(..)
                                                     .onErrorResume(..));
```

Is that possible at all? Because as I don't expose the `Mono` coming out of the `webClient.post()` request to the caller, I don't know how I could chain handler methods on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the transform operator here. I would not call this adding "consumers" but inserting additional operators at a specific point in the reactive pipeline. It would look something like:

```
public String blockingCall(Function<Mono<String>, Publisher<String>> transformer) {
    return Mono.just("hi")
               .transform(transformer)
               .block();
}
```

and use it like:

```
blockingCall(it -> it.doOnSuccess(...).doOnError(...))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use use `Mono#transform`. From the [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_using_the_transform_operator) of Reactor:

> The transform operator lets you encapsulate a piece of an operator chain into a function. That function is applied to an original operator chain at assembly time to augment it with the encapsulated operators. Doing so applies the same operations to all the subscribers of a sequence and is basically equivalent to chaining the operators directly.

In your case:

```java
public <Req, Rsp> List<Rsp> sendApiRequests(List<Req> requests, Class<Rsp> type, Function<Mono<Rsp>, Mono<Rsp>> subroutine) {
        return Flux.fromIterable(requests)
                .flatMap((Req req) -> webClient.post()
                        .uri(uri)
                        .bodyValue(req)
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToMono(type)
                        .transform(subroutine)
                )
                .filter(rsp -> rsp.success() && rsp.results > 0) //some common filters
                .collectList()
                .block();
    }
```